# Match Naming Convention of Text File Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find text files with a certain naming convention using regex, but have so far been unsuccessful.

The naming convention is `file_[year]-[month]-[day].txt` (eg. file_2010-09-15.txt).

Here is what I have so far: `^(file_)[0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2}(\.txt)$`

I'm trying to use it in my code like this:

```
    for text_file in os.listdir(path):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(text_file, '^(file_)[0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2}(\.txt)$'):
            # print number of files found
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your regex. Please include your code so we can see how you're using it.

Comment: What seems to be the issue? Also what are you trying to capture? In your example you will have two capture groups `file_` and `.txt`. Not sure what the desired output is

Comment: The regex is fine, if this is a python issue, please show where in python you use this regex?  https://regexr.com/3mvg1

Comment: So based off your update, I don't believe the `pattern` parameter does what you think it does. It seems to be more of a shell style pattern than an actual regex style.

Comment: @Chrispresso thank you for your response. Which method should I use that would be best for finding the type of file I'm looking for?

Comment: @Sicypher if you're set on using a regular expression try `re.match(pattern, string)`

Comment: @Chrispresso I'm not set on using regex. Is there something better to use here than that?

Comment: @Sicypher I think regex would be good here. Based off the documents https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html it looks like it supports Unix shell-style wild cards. Meaning I don't think it knows about `^`, `$`, `{}` or possible escaped characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is because of the `pattern` type that `fnmatch` is expecting. In the documents it states the following:

> This module provides support for Unix shell-style wildcards, which are not the same as regular expressions (which are documented in the re module). The special characters used in shell-style wildcards are:

```
Pattern Meaning
*   matches everything
?   matches any single character
[seq]   matches any character in seq
[!seq]  matches any character not in seq
```

`
You could keep it the way it is and just change it to that style of support, i.e.:

```
for text_file in os.listdir(path):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(text_file, 'file_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].txt'):
        # print number of files found
```

Or what I would suggest is using `re.match` like so:

```
regex = re.compile(r'^(file_)[0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2}(\.txt)$')
for text_file in os.listdir(path):
    if regex.match(text_file):
        # print the text file
```

Answer (score 1):

The `fnmatch` translates the `regex` to `re` python module. Take a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/fnmatch.py). Basically, the shortcuts supported are:

```
Patterns are Unix shell style:
*       matches everything
?       matches any single character
[seq]   matches any character in seq
[!seq]  matches any char not in seq
```

Your regex is should be: `'file_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].txt'`

Alternatively, you can get started with `re` directly, without using `fnmatch` (take a code below as a starting point, but there is room for improvement: check whether a year is a valid year, a month is between 1-12 and a day is between 1 and 28,29,30, or 31):

```
import re

example_file = 'file_2010-09-15.txt'

myregex = 'file_\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\.txt'

result = re.match(myregex, example_file)

print(result.group(0))
```

Comment: That makes my regex simpler! I'm trying to use your recommended regex with re.match(), but it's still not matching any files